# Input buttons style conflict with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the code below. I want to change the style size of the input buttons (white, blue and yellow....located at the bottom) without effecting the result of the code.

- The code compares table one's cells colors to the other tables and is supposed to display an alert when there is a match.
- You can change the color of table one's cells by selecting one of the bottom buttons (white, blue or yellow). Please help...

```js
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(function () {
 var brush = "white_block";
 jQuery('input.block').on('click', function () {
  brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
 });

 function cellCheck() {
  $one = $("#one").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
  $two = $("#two").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
  $three = $("#three").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
  $four = $("#four").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
  $five = $("#five").html().replace(/\s/g, '');

  if ($one === $two) {
   alert("match with two");
  }
  if ($one === $three) {
   alert("match with three");
  }
  if ($one === $four) {
   alert("match with four");
  }
  if ($one === $five) {
   alert("match with five");
  }
 }
 jQuery('td').on('click', function () {
  jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block blue_block yellow_block').addClass(brush);
  cellCheck();
 });
});
```

```css
.block {
 border: thin solid #000000;
 width: 59px;
 height: 57px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #d9d9d9,  2px 2px 0px #d9d9d9,  3px 3px 0px #d9d9d9,  4px 4px 0px #d9d9d9,  5px 5px 0px #d9d9d9,  6px 6px 0px #d9d9d9;
}
.button {
 border: thin solid #000000;
 width: 49px;
 height: 47px;
}
.white_block {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.blue_block {
 background-color: #0066cc;
}
.green_block {
 background-color: #00b300;
}
.red_block {
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
.yellow_block {
 background-color: #FFFF00;
}
table {
 margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<br>
<!--Table One:-->
<table id="one">
  <tr>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
    <td class="block white_block"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
<input type="button" class="block blue_block" data-brush="blue_block">
<input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
<div style="display:none"> <br>
  Table Two:
  <table id="two">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  Table Three:
  <table id="three">
    <tr>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  Table Four:
  <table id="four">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  Table Five:
  <table id="five">
    <tr>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block blue_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an extra class name to the input buttons.

```
<input type="button" class="block white_block wide_input" data-brush="white_block">
```

and modify the css however you want in your stylesheet.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56046138/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what i was looking for!